# Intention of Hadoop FS is to keep in RAM or disk?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

We are thinking about going with Hadoop in my company. From looking at the docs in the Internet I got the impression the idea of HDFS is to keep it in RAM to speed up things. Now our architects says that the main idea of HDFS is scalability. I'm fine with that. But then he also claims the main idea is to keep it on the on the harddisk. HDFS is basically a scalable harddisk. My opinion is that backing HDFS by the harddisk is an option. The main idea, however, is to keep it in RAM. Who is right now? I'm really confused now and the point is crucial for the understanding of Hadoop, I would say.

Thanks, Oliver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oliver, your architect is correct. **Horizontal scalability** is one of the biggest advantages of HDFS(Hadoop in general). When you say Hadoop it implies that you are dealing with very huge amounts of data, right? How are you going to put so much data in-memory?(I am assuming that by **the idea of HDFS is to keep it in RAM to speed up things** you mean to keep the data stored in HDFS in RAM).

But, the HDFS's metadata is kept in-memory so that you can quickly access the data stored in your HDFS. Remember, HDFS is not something physical. It is rather a virtual filesystem that lies on top of your native filesystem. So, when you say you are storing data into HDFS, it eventually gets stored in your native/local filesystem on your machine's disk and not RAM.

Having said that, there are certain major differences in the way HDFS and native FS behave. Like the block size which is very large when compared to local FS block size. Similarly the replicated manner in which data is stored in HDFS(think of RAID but at the software level).

**So how does HDFS make things faster?**

Hadoop is a distributed platform and HDFS a distributed store. When you put a file into HDFS it gets split into **n** small blocks(of size 64MB default, but configurable). Then all the blocks
of a file get stored across all the machines of your Hadoop cluster. This allows us to read all of the block together in parallel thus reducing the total reading time.

I would suggest you to go through this link in order to get a proper understanding of HDFS :
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hdfs_design.html

HTH